# Flutter: UpgradeAlert works OK, but with "upgrader: ..." parameter NOT?

Tags: flutter, upgrade

When the code is:

```
UpgradeAlert(
    child: Scaffold...
  )
```

Application detects new version in PlayStore and shows prompt.

When I add parameters:

```
UpgradeAlert(
  upgrader: Upgrader( messages: UpgraderMessages(code: 'pl'),
            showLater: false,
            showIgnore: false,
            durationUntilAlertAgain: Duration(minutes: 1), ),
```

child: Scaffold...
)

Application stops showing update alert, why?

Without "upgrader: Upgrader(...)," line works perfectly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLBhB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by not using localisations.

This is the `UpgradeAlert` I’m using:

```
var upgrader = Upgrader(
  showLater: false,
  showReleaseNotes: false,
  messages: MessagesUpgrader(),
)

GoRoute(
  path: '/login',
  builder: (context, state) => UpgradeAlert(
    upgrader: upgrader,
    navigatorKey: router.routerDelegate.navigatorKey,
    child: const LoginPage(),
  ),
),
```

And this is inside the `MessagesUpgrader()`:

```
class MessagesUpgrader extends UpgraderMessages {
  MessagesUpgrader();

  @override
  String get buttonTitleIgnore => 'No';

  @override
  String get buttonTitleUpdate => 'Yes';

  @override
  String get body => 'Some text here in the body';

  @override
  String get prompt => 'Another text here';
}
```

Before I had localisations in the `MessagesUpgrader` and I had a `BuildContext` to fetch those texts—but if this class doesn't refresh or rebuild, it works.

Not really a solution but a workaround until this issue is fixed.

Comment: Yes, declaring variable upgrader helped.
var upgrader = Upgrader(
  showLater: false,
  showReleaseNotes: false,
  messages: MessagesUpgrader(),
)

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Can you upvote the answer or give it the right answer so others can see it?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have enaught reputation to upvote :-(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, when I declare parameters in variable:

```
    var upgrader = Upgrader(
  showLater: false,
  showReleaseNotes: false,
  messages: MessagesUpgrader(),
)
```

and...

```
UpgradeAlert(
  upgrader: upgrader,
```

Instead of placing it directly in UpgradeAlert

```
 UpgradeAlert(
  upgrader: Upgrader( messages: UpgraderMessages(code: 'pl'),
            showLater: false,
            showIgnore: false,
            durationUntilAlertAgain: Duration(minutes: 1), ),
child: Scaffold... )
```